# How to add options for Pages?

Tags: options, settings-api

I would like to show an input field on the bottom, everytime, when a user create a new page. How is it possible?

Comment: See [tag:metabox] – does that answer your question?

Comment: Fine. :) My suggestion: remove this question, and ask new questions when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about Custom Fields? I would recommend reading this part of the codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields#Usage